# Override accessibility environment values in SwiftUI snapshot tests?

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, snapshot-testing

I'm writing snapshot tests for SwiftUI views using the [Point-Free snapshot test library](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing). I'd like to test that my views respond correctly to the following SwiftUI environment properties:

- `accessibilityDifferentiateWithoutColor`
- `accessibilityReduceTransparency`
- `accessibilityReduceMotion`
- `accessibilityInvertColors`

How can I override these values in my tests?

Answer (score 0):

There are public-but-undocumented, underscored versions of these symbols that can be used to override their values in tests:

- `_accessibilityDifferentiateWithoutColor`
- `_accessibilityReduceTransparency`
- `_accessibilityReduceMotion`
- `_accessibilityInvertColors`

Usage:

```swift
someView
    .environment(\._accessibilityShowButtonShapes, true)
```

It is my understanding that these values are intentionally provided by Apple for testing purposes.